# Making all Apps on a Server Use SQL Session Manager

Tags: .net, sql-server, session, web-config, app-config

Is there any way to make all the applications on a server use SQL Server as the session manager?

The reason is that we have a server with hundreds of applications and we want to start load balancing the server but it will be a big hassle to configure each individual application to use SQL Server as the session manager.  It will also prevent from human error when deploying an application if the user forgets to set it up as SQL Session Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specifiy the SQLServer session manager in \Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\web.config

Comment: will this override the application's web.config if it has  <sessionState mode="InProc" /> or will this only work if the setting has not been set?

Comment: The application should not set it in their web.config. If they do, then Application setting would take precedence.